# Should a collection be encapsulated inside a class if I am avoiding Primitive Obsession?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

Please see the code below:

```
public class Customer
{
    private readonly IList<Order> _orders = new List<Order>();

    public FirstName FirstName { get; set; }
    public LastName LastName { get; set; }
    public Province Province { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Order> Orders 
    {
        get { foreach (var order in _orders) yield return order; }
    }

    internal void AddOrder(Order order)
    {
        _orders.Add(order);
    }
}
```

Notice that I have removed Primitive Obsession for FirstName; LastName and Province.  Notice that I also have a list of Orders, which is returned via an IEnumerable.  I asked this question last month: [What is the benefit of encapsulating a collection inside a class?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/361359/what-is-the-benefit-of-encapsulating-a-collection-inside-a-class)

I decided not to encapsulate the list inside an object in the end.  However, does this still have the Primitive Obsession smell? I am trying to avoid Primitive Obsession consistently.

Should I be doing:

```
private readonly OrderList _orders = OrderList();
```

Instead of:

```
private readonly IList<Order> _orders = new List<Order>();
```

Comment: I don't see any primitives here. I think you mean you're avoiding (not using) primitive obsession. Which is fine since it is a code smell. If so, please edit your question.

Comment: @CandiedOrange, thanks.  I have updated my question.  Does that help?

Comment: You only fixed 1 of 3 places that have that problem.

Comment: @CandiedOrange, sorry I don't know what you mean.  Could you clarify?

Comment: See the questions title and the end of your question. You are not "trying to use Primitive Obsession consistently" you are "trying to avoid Primitive Obsession consistently". And primitive obsession is a smell. Not a rule.

Comment: @CandiedOrange, thanks.  I have edited the question again.

Comment: And again you've still not updated the questions title and are still calling primitive obsession a rule. It's a smell. Not a rule.

Comment: I have changed the title as well, thanks.  I am asking if using a list (instead of encapsulating a list inside an object - like the link in my question) violates primitive obsession.

Comment: You're about halfway there. The title shouldn't say "using avoiding Primitive Obsession".  It should just be "avoiding Primitive Obsession". And at the end you are still calling this a rule. It's not a rule you violate or don't. It's a smell you avoid or don't. Can you see what I mean?

Comment: BTW, if you store your private List of Orders as a `List` instead of `IList`, you can just return it from your public `IEnumerable` instead of yielding from a loop.

Comment: Personally, unless there's actual business logic tied to your `FirstName` and `LastName` classes, I consider using them instead of a basic `string` to be a smell. Slavishly following a principle even when it makes the code worse is not good either.

Comment: @Bobson, these classes would contain validation logic. Also if you are going through the code with a Business Analyst or SME, then they understand the concept of FirstNames and ages rather than strings and integers.

Comment: @w0051977 Fair point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A collection does not need to be encapsulated inside a class to avoid primitive obsession. Your code example already avoids using primitives throughout.

Had you exposed a collection `private IList<String> _emailAddresses = ...`, then you would maybe want to consider creating an Email class that eliminated using the built in String type.

Answer (score 5):

First, let’s flip “avoiding primitive obsession” from a negative into the positive we’re trying to achieve, “Strong Typing”.

This means we don’t want to accidentally assign a temperature in Fahrenheit to a variable that’s meant to hold a Celsius temperature.

So, instead of

```
double temp = 23.2;
double temp2 = 75.7;

//... lots of code

temp2 = temp; //BUG!
```

We want

```
Celsius temp = new Celsius(23.2);
Fahrenheit temp2 = new Fahrenheit(75.7);

//... lots of code

temp2 = temp; // Won’t compile. No bug!
```

Now let’s think for a moment about how we say this signature in English.

```
IEnumerable<Order>
```

We say “IEnumerable of Order”.  This type is already strongly typed. We can’t assign an `IEnumerable<Customer>` to variables of type `IEnumerable<Order>`. 
Your code is fine as is.